# SQLAlchemy db interactions fail depending how I run the python script

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, supervisord, alembic

This seems to be the most obscure issue I have dealt with so far. I am struggling hard.

I have an application that collects remote data from some hardware and saves it to a database. I renamed one of the columns using `alembic`. I have a development database and a testing database. Both are on the same server (`MySQL` via `MariaDB` on `CentOS 7`).

I interact with the development server via the app running on my laptop and the testing db is interacted with via the app running on a clone of the production server.

All servers and databases are set up using `Ansible`, so differences are limited to usernames and passwords.

Below is the `ansible` snippet from the upgrade script

```
def upgrade():
    op.alter_column('units', 'ip_address', new_column_name='ipv4', existing_type=sa.String(100))
```

If I run the app from my laptop (using my IDE), the data is saved ok.

If I run the script on the testing server manually `(env)$ python app.py`, the data is saved ok.

But, here's the problem, If I run the script using `supervisord`, I get an SQLAlchemy error. (excerpts below, [full traceback](http://pastebin.com/aWiWE3Ff))

```
...
File "thefile.py", line 64, in run
    self.data['my_wellsites'][w.name]['ipv4'] = wellsite.unit.ipv4
...
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (InternalError) (1054, u"Unknown column 'units.ipv4' in 'field list'") 'SELECT units.id AS units_id, units.unittype_id AS units_unittype_id, units.serial AS units_serial, units.ipv4 AS units_ipv4, units.mac_address AS units_mac_address, units.engine_hours AS units_engine_hours, units.gen_odometer AS units_gen_odometer, units.gen_periodic AS units_gen_periodic, units.notes AS units_notes \nFROM units \nWHERE units.id = %s' (1,)
...
```

SQLAlchemy models..

```
class Unit(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'units'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('unit_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    wellsites = relationship('Wellsite', order_by='Wellsite.id', backref='unit')
    ipv4 = Column(String(16), unique=True)
    ...

class Wellsite(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wellsites'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('wellsite_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    unit_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('units.id'), nullable=False)
    ...
```

etc/supervisord.conf..

```
...
[program:datacollect]
command = /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/bin/python /home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/data_monitoring/collection_manager.py
stdout_logfile=/home/webdev/logs/datacollect.log
stderr_logfile=/home/webdev/logs/datacollecterr.log
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
startsecs=10
```

I tried running an additional `alembic` upgrade with

```
op.create_unique_constraint('uq_ipv4', 'units', ['ipv4'])
```

No dice.

The `traceback` is identical (using diff program) except timestamps

Here are the two database descriptions of the `units` table (identical)

```
MariaDB [ers_DEV]> show columns from units;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| unittype_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| serial       | varchar(10)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| ipv4         | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| mac_address  | varchar(17)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| engine_hours | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gen_odometer | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gen_periodic | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notes        | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


MariaDB [ers_TEST]> show columns from units;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| unittype_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| serial       | varchar(10)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| ipv4         | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| mac_address  | varchar(17)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| engine_hours | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notes        | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gen_odometer | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gen_periodic | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was at the top of the `/etc.supervisord.conf` file. In it, an environment variable is set that was pointing the script to the wrong database, overriding the environment variable that was set and examined from anywhere else. This environment variable is only set when the script is being run from `supervisor` and was causing the trouble